How to change the speed of truck agent in region in Anylogic
I've developed a supply chain simulation model using Anylogic to analyze the impact of traffic in a specific region near warehouse. I've collected average speed data over the past seven years using sensor, but I'm encountering issues with the truck agents' behavior when they enter this area. Some trucks exhibit erratic movement, like moving back and forth, while others show no change in behavior. I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to resolve this.[GIS region and moveTo block](https://i.sstatic.net/E8wo7iZP.jpg)
What I expect is that when truck agent enter this region, it's speed reduce to 20 mile per hour and when exit, it's speed change to 70 mph. However, the results are strange as I explained.

PS: Only use the "anylogic" tag, that suffices

you need to use the setSpeed() method, your code does not change actual agent speeds, just some local fields you created.
Check some example models and the help to learn how to use it. Then, create a tiny example model yourself to make it work. Then, apply to your model :)
